# Arduino stops looping after the 7th time

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a distance sensor and servo attached to my Arduino. After the 7th reading, the loop stops, and nothing else is added to the serial monitor. Any clue why?

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(9);
  delay(15);
}

void loop() {
  const int analogInPin = A0;
  int sensorValue = 0;
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  int outputValue = 0;
  outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 255, 0);
  Serial.println(outputValue);
  myservo.write(outputValue);
  delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 255, 0);
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
  outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
```

> Syntax
>
> `map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)`
>
> Parameters
>
> value: the number to map
>
> fromLow: the lower bound of the value’s current range
>
> fromHigh: the upper bound of the value’s current range
>
> toLow: the lower bound of the value’s target range
>
> toHigh: the upper bound of the value’s target range

As you code is, now, the higher you go, the lower `outputValue` will be... So if you yank the pot (or whatever you've connected on `A0`) all the way up, `outputValue` will be 0. And the servo will be told to stop.

Comment: It ended up being a bad board. Switched out, problem solved. I was instructed to map to 255, 0